# Is there any way to get resque-web to work with Redis To Go hosted redis instance?

Tags: ruby, redis, resque

Is there any way to get resque-web to work with a Redis To Go hosted redis instance?

UPDATE:

@Nemo157's suggestion was correct. Ended up creating a test-evn.rb containing:

```
uri = URI.parse(" redis://XXXX@catfish.redistogo.com:9122")
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it the config file you're using to setup redis in the app, e.g.

```
resque-web ./environment.rb
```

where `environment.rb` contains something like:

```
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => "path.to.host", :port => 6379)
```

Note: I haven't tested this since all my redis instances have been on `localhost`, but that's my understanding of how it works.

Comment: That's kind of a hack, you can use the cli variable: RAILS_RESQUE_REDIS